# Google Map in jQuery Mobile page, zoom feature not rendering properly

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I'm building a jQuery Mobile page that incorporates a Google map (API v3). So far I have been successful displaying the map and implementing a lot of functionality. My problem is that the zoom feature on the google map does not render properly (it looks broken up and pixely).

The code at the bottom of the page demonstrates a basic implementation of a Google map in jQuery Mobile. If you test it on the latest version of Firefox you should see the zoom problem. Notice if you comment any of the three libraries below the zoom feature renders properly but the jQuery mobile functionality is lost.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
```

The research I've done indicates that the libraries implemented in [these](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html) examples might fix the issue, but it will require me re-writing a large number of methods. Can any one advise me on a simpler way to fix this.

Sample Code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map_canvas {
            height: 375px;
            width: 550px;
            padding:10px;
            border:1px solid gray;
            margin:10px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.332619, -121.88440100000003),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the plugin you mentioned (http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html) and recommend you to use this with jQM.
The plugin also struggles with some rendering failures on jQM and recommends to refresh all maps on `pageshow`.

Leads to code like:

```
jQuery(document).bind('pageshow', function(e, data) {
    var page = jQuery(e.target);
    page.find('.gmap').gmap('refresh');
});
```

You should try to do this somehow without the plugin.